# Extracting text data from multiple lists of XML using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am working on parsing an xml file (150mb) in size. For that since beautifulsoup is well known, so I picked it up. 
The xml format is like this:

```
<tag>
  <tag1>
   <texttag>Some text</texttag>
  </tag1>
 </tag>

<tag>
  <tag1>
   <texttag>Some other text</texttag>
  </tag1>
 </tag>
```

I am having two thousand such elements.
Since a root tag is not here so I split it on the basis of the main tag of each element since its the same and converted into lists (again two thousand of them). Here is how it goes:

```
import itertools as it
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
filename = 'some.xml'
btree = BeautifulSoup(open(filename), "lxml-xml")

with open(filename,'r') as f:
 for key,group in it.groupby(f,lambda line: line.startswith('tag')):
    if not key:
        group = list(group)
        #print(group)
        texttags= btree.find_all("texttag")
        for text in texttags:
          print (text.string)
```

On running instead of iterating to the next element and displaying its text and so on, it displays the first element's text 2000 times instead of displaying text from all the elements with the mentioned tag. Can someone please rectify me on this?

PS: I cannot modify the structure of the XML. Also, I am an amateur still dabbling in python and its libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im afraid you can't use `lxml-xml` for this document because it will only grab the first tag.
However you can use `lxml` or `html.parser`.

```
btree = BeautifulSoup(open(filename), "html.parser")
texttags= btree.find_all("texttag")
for text in texttags:
    print(text.string)
```

Alternatively, if you must use `lxml-xml`, you could use `html.parser` to collect tags, then build a new `BeautifulSoup` object and append tags to the root tag.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filename), "html.parser")
btree = BeautifulSoup("<root></root>", "lxml-xml")

for tag in soup.find_all('tag'):
    btree.root.append(tag)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @t.m.adam. I do get my result correctly but it takes quite some time. I mean my xml file is by no means a small one, but still can you suggest anything to improve the speed of getting the result?

Comment: If you just want to extract strings use the first code snippet in my post; and use `lxml` instead of `html.parser`. If you're only interested in a certain tag consider regular expressions, it's much faster than bs4.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors. First, instead of open("filename") you need open(filename). In your code you basically operate two files instead of one: 'some.xml' and 'filename'.

Second, there is no need to open a file with open(...) after you parsed it with BeautifulSoup. The whole code should be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
filename = 'some.xml'
btree = BeautifulSoup(open(filename), "lxml-xml")

texttags= btree.find_all("texttag")
for text in texttags:
    print (text.string)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I rectified the first mistake.
For the second one, if there was a single root element it will work  straight away. 
But in my case , no root element is present. Instead an element is repeated multiple times with different data. That is why I had to split the XML and convert each element into a list on which I am performing find_all and then iterating. Its on the iteration part that I am failing.